# how to properly do a select in a multi to multi table relation

Tags: mysql, select

I have this query

```
SELECT f.id_film, title, year, GROUP_CONCAT(actor SEPARATOR '|') AS 'actors',
GROUP_CONCAT(director SEPARATOR '|') AS 'directors' 
FROM film f JOIN middle m ON f.id_film = m.id_film
JOIN actors a ON m.id_name = a.id_actor 
JOIN directors d ON m.id_name = d.id_director 
WHERE id_category = "com" GROUP BY f.id_film
```

which should gather names from table actors and table directors. The middle table is actually a "joiner" between the two tables and differentiates one from the other with a column "type" holding either "a" or "d" value. I'm unable to properly separate actors from directors meaning the query return all id's regardless of type. I have tried sub-queries with no success. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing to include "type" field comparison of middle table while joining to actor and director tables,

Try below:

```
SELECT f.id_film, title, year, GROUP_CONCAT(actor SEPARATOR '|') AS 'actors',
GROUP_CONCAT(director SEPARATOR '|') AS 'directors' 
FROM film f JOIN middle m ON f.id_film = m.id_film
LEFT JOIN actors a ON m.id_name = a.id_actor AND m.type = 'a'
LEFT JOIN directors d ON m.id_name = d.id_director AND m.type = 'd'
WHERE id_category = "com" GROUP BY f.id_film
```

@michael See [**`SqlFiddle`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30f14/1) , You need to put your database schema statements and insert sample data statements on left side , and you can provide link and expected output in your question so we can try the solution on sample data.

Comment: @michael Can you create SqlFiddle with your db structure and sample data, that will help others to understand and try the solution. thanks

Comment: sorry I don't know what SqlFiddle is if you explain that to me I'll do it

Comment: @michael can you try with LEFT JOIN for actors and directors table, I have edited my answer, please check now

Comment: genius! if beside that you also were a beauty contestant I would kiss you

Comment: @michael For now I will be happy just to get up vote and tick mark against my answer :)